# My Grub2 is perfect, except I can't update it other than manually (editing grub.cfg). How do I clean this up?

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, opensuse, boot-loader

I'm running openSUSE Tumbleweed on an Acer laptop. Please feel free to ask for any hardware / software details that may be important in the comments.

My problem is:

```
> sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg    
insmod: ERROR: could not load module part_msdos: No such file or directory
```

However I think I know where the problem comes from: my `/etc/default/grub` is identical (very long and complicated) to my `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. (and when I remove every instance of `part_msdos` in `/etc/default/grub`, I get another error, and then yet another... It's endless).

In order to fix that, I saved the old `grub` file and replaced it with a clean, "new" one, with only entries like `GRUB_DEFAULT=` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=`.

Then I could generate a new `grub.cfg`, but of course at boot everything failed immediatly and I ended up in `grub-repair >`.

So here's my real problem: I would like the `grub2-mkconfig` command to actually work so that I could update my Grub with it, but... My current Grub looks, feels and behaves perfectly at boot so I want to preserve it.

I have no idea if this is even possible, but if someone knows what to do...

Thanks!

---

***EDIT***: here's what I did, from listening to you.

1. I backed up `/etc/default/grub` and then erased it, and replaced it with a `grub` file in the same location containing this:

```
#/etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="false"
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub2/jinx-resized.png"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/openSUSE/theme.txt"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
```

2. Then I ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.
3. The result? A black grub, with just two entries: `openSUSE Tumbleweed` and `Recovery for openSUSE Tumbleweed` (containing 4 entries). **All 5 entries crash when I try to boot on them**.

So? Everything in `etc/grub.d` is executable, including `30_os-prober`.

Here I let you see the result of what I did:

```
#/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
set btrfs_relative_path="n"
export btrfs_relative_path
if [ -f ${config_directory}/grubenv ]; then
  load_env -f ${config_directory}/grubenv
elif [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi

if [ "${env_block}" ] ; then
  set env_block="(${root})${env_block}"
  export env_block
  load_env -f "${env_block}"
fi

if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   if [ "${env_block}" ] ; then
     save_env -f "${env_block}" next_entry
   fi
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    if [ "${env_block}" ] ; then
      save_env -f "${env_block}" saved_entry
    else
      save_env saved_entry
    fi

  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}


for i in console; do
  if [ x${use_append} = xtrue ]; then
     terminal_output --append $i
  elif terminal_output $i; then
     use_append=true;
  fi
done

if [ x${boot_once} = xtrue ]; then
  set timeout=0
elif [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###
set tuned_params=""
set tuned_initrd=""
### END /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_crypttab ###
### END /etc/grub.d/05_crypttab ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_menu_color ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_menu_color ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed'  --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
    savedefault
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.8-1-default ...'
    linux   /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.8-1-default root=UUID=37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a rootflags=subvol=@/.snapshots/709/snapshot resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/initrd-6.5.8-1-default
}
submenu 'Advanced options for openSUSE Tumbleweed' --hotkey=1 $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 6.5.8-1-default' --hotkey=2 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.8-1-default-advanced-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
    savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.8-1-default ...'
        linux   /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.8-1-default root=UUID=37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a rootflags=subvol=@/.snapshots/709/snapshot resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/initrd-6.5.8-1-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 6.5.8-1-default (recovery mode)' --hotkey=3 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.8-1-default-recovery-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.8-1-default ...'
        linux   /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.8-1-default root=UUID=37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a single rootflags=subvol=@/.snapshots/709/snapshot resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/initrd-6.5.8-1-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 6.5.6-1-default'  --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.6-1-default-advanced-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
    savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.6-1-default ...'
        linux   /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.6-1-default root=UUID=37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a rootflags=subvol=@/.snapshots/709/snapshot resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/initrd-6.5.6-1-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 6.5.6-1-default (recovery mode)' --hotkey=1 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.6-1-default-recovery-37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.6-1-default ...'
        linux   /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.6-1-default root=UUID=37b1ace3-0889-4b40-9b0a-a2fe5da56d0a single rootflags=subvol=@/.snapshots/709/snapshot resume=UUID=2b54516c-b818-4bfb-8305-28b0a17182d9 quiet splash
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /@/.snapshots/709/snapshot/boot/initrd-6.5.6-1-default
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
                fwsetup --is-supported
                if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
                        fwsetup
                else
                        echo "Your firmware doesn't support setup menu entry from a boot loader"
                        echo "Press any key to return ..."
                        read
                fi
        }
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/80_suse_btrfs_snapshot ###
### END /etc/grub.d/80_suse_btrfs_snapshot ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/90_persistent ###
### END /etc/grub.d/90_persistent ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/95_textmode ###
if [ "${grub_platform}" = "efi" ]; then
  # On EFI systems we can only have graphics *or* serial, so allow the user
  # to switch between the two
  hiddenentry 'Text mode' --hotkey 't' {
    set textmode=true
    terminal_output console
  }
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/95_textmode ###
```

My quick analysis: Grub created all entries of Tumbleweed pointing to kernels and initramfs from *snapshots*, that do not necessarily exist anymore.
And os prober didn't do anything.
Btw, I had not added anything yet to `40_custom`, though I do have the executable file.

**End word:** thanks God I backed everything up and did not trust the omnipresent "Fix your `/etc/default/grub`, then re-create your config and you will be fine!"

For any future reader: I'm very sorry for the angry tone of that post, it's just that I feel kind of betrayed when people make it sound super easy and it not only doesn't work but breaks everything. Sorry again

Comment: I don't specifically know Tumbleweed, but if it is similar to SLES 15, then setting `SUSE_BTRFS_SNAPSHOT_BOOTING=false` in `/etc/default/grub` should eliminate the snapshots trickery. The `30_os-prober` looks for *other operating systems* in dual/multiboot scenarios: it has nothing to do with booting the OS you're running `grub2-mkconfig` in.

Comment: Your problem is not `/etc/default/grub`. Something more basic is broken on your system. It shouldn't happen that grub's `10_linux` script creates menuentries with kernels from snapshots. Those who advised you to just recreate `/etc/default/grub` couldn't know that. It's hard to say how such a situation can come to pass. I would start with a clean reinstall of grub2 (`zypper in --force grub2`). If this still happens, I'd suggest to insert a `set -x` at the top of `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and figure out why it is selecting this weird kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You have written GRUB configuration commands directly into `/etc/default/grub`. That is not correct: `/etc/default/grub` is sourced by the `grub2-mkconfig` script to be a part of **a shell script that will create the actual `grub.cfg`**. Other parts of that shell script are located in `/etc/grub.d/`.

If you write `insmod part_msdos` into `/etc/default/grub`, then `grub-mkconfig` will attempt to execute a *Linux* command to load a *Linux kernel module* named `part_msdos`, which obviously doesn't exist - instead of adding a line to GRUB configuration that tells it to load the *GRUB* module `part_msdos`.

Normally, `/etc/default/grub` is supposed to contain only variable assignments to be used by the other script components in `/etc/grub.d/`.

If you wish to completely write your own GRUB configuration, you should name it `/boot/grub/custom.cfg`. The very last script called by `grub2-mkconfig`, `/etc/grub.d/41_custom`, adds a few lines to the end of any "standard" `grub.cfg` produced by it, to make GRUB source the `custom.cfg` if it exists. That could be used to completely override the "standard-style" GRUB configuration with your custom one.

Alternatively, if you want to keep some parts of the `grub2-mkconfig` functionality but replace others, you should look at the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/`: each of the scripts will be responsible for a particular part of the "standard" `grub.cfg` file. You could modify or even completely replace some of those scripts.

Note that you cannot just write GRUB configuration language directly into most of these scripts: you must write **a shell script that will output your desired GRUB configuration** to standard output.

In particular, if you only want to add custom commands (e.g. menu entries for other OSs) after the standard menu produced by `grub2-mkconfig`, you should just write your GRUB commands to the end of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` - that's exactly what that script is there for. It has a clever two-line header that causes the rest of the script to be sent to the standard output as-is, allowing you to write straight GRUB configuration syntax.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of most of what you said... What you didn't say, though, is how to cleanly replace my corrupted `/etc/default/grub` with a functional, customizable one? Isn't there a way to do this automatically, or even better based on your `grub.cfg`?

Comment: No, there is no automatic way to map your custom `grub.cfg` back into standard components - because a standard component corresponding to your (unspecified) customizations might not exist. It might be necessary to compare your custom `grub.cfg` to the standard `grub2-mkconfig`-produced one side-by-side to figure out what they are doing differently.

Comment: @UlTome You should be able to get back a "fresh" `/etc/default/grub` by reinstalling the grub *package* (NOT grub-install) with your package manager, although some package manager might require you to specify the desire explicitly instead of just having the file deleted, IIRC.